# Trailhead : Lightning Web Components basic error when deploying to devhub

Tags: trailhead, lightning-web-components

Hello I have the following errors when trying to deploy ebikes to devhub :

```
=== Deploy Errors
PROJECT PATH  ERROR
────────────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
N/A           Can't create lightning component bundle if there is already an aura definition bundle with the same name and namespace.
N/A           The c:accountMap component isn't allowed in the sidebar region. The component doesn't implement any of the region's allowed interfaces.
N/A           Cannot find Lightning Component Bundle accountMap.
N/A           Cannot find Lightning Component Bundle accountMap.
```

I can see there is a `bikeCard lwc` in the org but created just seconds before the deployment. (that's the only `lwc` in the org along with a `helloWorld test`)
An ideas ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have a lightning aura component named `accountMap`? That's what the error suggests.

Comment: That is exactly that THANKS !!!

Comment: You may like to add that as an answer, so that this question stands resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was given in comment but not posted as an answer.

So, the error suggests that there is already a lightning aura component named `accountMap`. To resolve this issue, either delete `accountMap` aura component or create a fresh new trailhead organization.

Comment: How should I know which one to delete, the aura or the lwc?

Comment: if you are trying to deploy a new component with the same name, delete the existing component with this name, this is simple